# How to add multiple new columns to a Pandas Dataframe without fragmentation causing a None object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, calculated-columns

I'm running several loops of code on a pandas dataframe which should add new columns.
There are several blocks but they basically look like this:

```
Bbands_list = [-3,-2.5,-2,-1.5,-1,0, -0.5,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3]
SMA_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,14,16,18,20,21,22,24,26,28,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100,125,150,175,200]
for m in SMA_list:
    for b in Bbands_list:
        name = 'M' + str(m) + "B" + str(b)
        df[name] = df['Close'].rolling(m).mean() + (df['Close'].rolling(m).std() * b)
        df[name] = (df[name] - df['Close'])/df['Close']
```

But when I run the code, I get this error:

```
PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead.  To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
  df[name] = (df['Close'].rolling(5).std() - df['Close'].rolling(5).std(i))/df['Close'].rolling(5).std()
```

My understanding was that this was just a performance warning, and I have plenty of memory so I've ignored it in the past, or made a fresh copy after the loops, to have a defragmented copy. But this time, whenever I run the code, it keeps ending with the df now being equal to 'None'. Any idea what might be going on or how I can fix this?
I've tried `df = df.copy()` but no matter where in the code I place this, it doesn't change anything

Comment: using loops to populate a DataFrame is usually a bad practice and often (but not always) can be replaced with vectorial code. You should really provide a data sample and explain the logic you're trying to achieve

Comment: The example itself and the goal is quite complicated, but is largely irrelevant to the question, which is a question of structure and how best to append records to the dataframe. This is why I left it out. You can also clearly see vectorised code within each iteration of the loop, but I can't see how I would go about vectorising the loop itself. Anyway, thanks for your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @mozway, don't append records to a dataframe. Prefer collect data in a python structure (dict, list) and the concatenate it to create a DataFrame. Something like:

```
from itertools import product

data = {}  # <- a dict
for m, b in product(*[SMA_list, Bbands_list]):
    data[f"M{m}_B{b}"] = (df['Close'].rolling(m).mean() + df['Close'].rolling(m).std() * b - df['Close']) / df['Close']
out = pd.concat(data, axis=1)  # <- the dataframe
```